# Adding new Xarray DataArray to an existing Zarr store without re-writing the whole dataset?

Tags: dask, python-xarray, zarr

How do I add a new `DataArray` to an existing `Dataset` without overwriting the whole thing?  The new `DataArray` shares some coordinates with the existing one, but also has new ones.  In my current implementation, the `Dataset` gets completely overwritten, instead of just adding the new stuff.

The existing `DataArray` is a chunked zarr-backed `DirectoryStore` (though I have the same problem for an S3 store).

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import zarr

arr1 = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2, 3),
                   [('x', ['a', 'b']), ('y', [10, 20, 30])],
                   name='arr1')

ds = arr1.chunk({'x': 1, 'y': 3}).to_dataset()
```

`ds` looks like this:

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) int64 10 20 30
Data variables:
    arr1     (x, y) float64 dask.array<shape=(2, 3), chunksize=(1, 3)>
```

I write it to a directory store:

```py
store = zarr.DirectoryStore('test.zarr')
z = ds.to_zarr(store, group='arr', mode='w')
```

It looks good:

```sh
$ ls -l test.zarr/arr
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  6 myuser  mygroup  204 Sep 21 11:03 arr1
drwxr-xr-x  5 myuser  mygroup  170 Sep 21 11:03 x
drwxr-xr-x  5 myuser  mygroup  170 Sep 21 11:03 y
```

I create a new `DataArray` that shares some coordinates with the existing one, and add it to the existing `Dataset`. I'll read the existing `Dataset` first, since that's what I'm doing in practice.

```py
ds2 = xr.open_zarr(store, group='arr')
arr2 = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(2, 3),
                   [('x', arr1.x), ('z', [1, 2, 3])],
                   name='arr2')
ds2['arr2'] = arr2
```

The updated `Dataset` looks fine:

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3, z: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) int64 10 20 30
  * z        (z) int64 1 2 3
Data variables:
    arr1     (x, y) float64 dask.array<shape=(2, 3), chunksize=(1, 3)>
    arr2     (x, z) float64 0.4728 1.118 0.7275 0.4971 -0.3398 -0.3846
```

...but I can't write to it without a complete overwrite.

```py
# I think I'm "appending" to the group `arr`
z2 = ds2.to_zarr(store, group='arr', mode='a')
```

This gives me a `ValueError: The only supported options for mode are 'w' and 'w-'.`

```py
# I think I'm "creating" the new arr2 array in the arr group
z2 = ds2.to_zarr(store, group='arr', mode='w-')
```

This gives me `ValueError: path 'arr' contains a group`.

The only thing that worked is `z2 = ds2.to_zarr(store, group='arr', mode='w')`, but this completely overwrites the group.

The original `DataArray` is actually quite large in my problem, so I really don't want to re-write it.  **Is there a way to only write the new `DataArray`?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It's been a while since this question was posted - but maybe it's still relevant ad helpful to someone (to me it was!)

Version `0.16.2` of `xarray` introduced the keyword region to `to_zarr`, which lets you write to limited region of a zarr file. This seemingly enables you to add a new variable to an existing dataset, without overwriting it entirely.

My solution picks up after you've written `ds` to the zarr and created the new `ds2` in memory, just before writing it back.

First, I'm keeping the *modified* times of each zarr content in a dictionary, to check after the second write if indeed nothing has changed:

```py
import os
import glob

mtimes = {}
contents = list(glob.glob("test.zarr/arr/*"))
for c in contents:
    mtimes.update({c: os.path.getmtime(c)})
```

Now I can write back the new variable. To use the `region` keyword, I need to drop any variables that exist already and are the same for both variables:

```py
ds2_dropped = ds2.drop(["x", "y", "z", "arr1"])
```

Now I can write the new variable and check the modified times if indeed nothing has changed:

```py
ds2_dropped.to_zarr("test.zarr/", mode="a", group='arr', region={"x": slice(0, ds2.x.size), "z": slice(0, ds2.z.size)})

for c in contents:
    assert os.path.getmtime(c) == mtimes[c]

# all good!
```

And if we load the dataset from zarr again, we can see that the new variable has been added sucessfully:

```py
print(xr.open_zarr("test.zarr/", group="arr"))

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3, z: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) <U1 'a' 'b'
  * y        (y) int64 10 20 30
Dimensions without coordinates: z
Data variables:
    arr1     (x, y) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 3), meta=np.ndarray>
    arr2     (x, z) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(2, 3), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unluckily, this is (to the best of my knowledge) currently not possible. The `to_zarr` in append mode is implemented to add new entries to a dimension and not variables to already written entries.

@davidbrochart wrote a good [example](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/pull/2706#issuecomment-458720920) in the original MR for the use case:

```py
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

ds0 = xr.Dataset({'temperature': (['time'],  [50, 51, 52])}, coords={'time': pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=3)})
ds1 = xr.Dataset({'temperature': (['time'],  [53, 54, 55])}, coords={'time': pd.date_range('2000-01-04', periods=3)})

ds0.to_zarr('temp')
ds1.to_zarr('temp', mode='a', append_dim='time')

ds2 = xr.open_zarr('temp')
```

You will see that `ds2` is the concatenated version of `ds0` and `ds1` over the time dimension.

The good news is that there is an option to interact with the zarr store directly. If you look at the implementation xarray [uses](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/69c85b85a1ef5d13b6ca51b6b655a1f719cc5abf/xarray/backends/zarr.py#L230), you can see that adding new variables is actually a possibility in the underlying [zarr](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library. This is however not implemented in the xarray API.